# Jquery easy UI Slider with range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-easyui

In my Project i'm using Jquery easy UI Slider.

I don't know how to achieve range slider in jquery easy ui like jqueryui range slider

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

How can i make jquery easyui slider with range

Comment: In easyui document there is nothing about range slider   http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#  under form see slider

Answer (score 0):

Try to reproduce example in https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range. click on `API Documentation` link, go to bottom and copy code. create new html file and paste that code in it. create new .css and .js file by pasting belwo url in browser and save the content as with respective .js and .css files like jquery-ui.css, jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-ui.js.

```
"//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
"//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"
```

save these files to your folder and change the files path in html accordingly. You can see running slider on you side and try to understand the implementation and use it in your project

html Walk through `API Documentation` for more details

Comment: Shiva want to create a slider using EasyUI like the range slider in jQuery UI(not using jQuery UI).